# How to disable table view scroll in UITableViewCell class rather than in the UITableView view class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Consider you are having the table view with a separate cell class that will be registered for table view later.

Now, we know how to disable the table view scroll using the table view instance, like in the below line.

tableView.isScrollEnabled = true/false

But what if I require to show some coach marks on the cell class, And I need to lock the table view scroll until that coach marks disappear using cell rather than table view. Because for a cell class table view instance is inaccessible since cell is within table view, not the table view within cell.

I've achieved this by using Notifications and Observers. But Please let me know if this can be achieved in any other way.

Comment: This should be in your model : the tableView should not display thing that do not need to be displayed and so no scrolling can be done.

Comment: you mean to say, I should not place the coach marks view inside the table view cell?

Comment: No : the coach mark can be in the cell but should only represent the state of some data in your model.

Comment: @THEJAS could you update your question to make your logic flow clear?
When will coachmark disappear? what cause it? When will it display? etc

Answer (score 1):

Is your target supporting iOS 13+? If so you can use Combine SDK. It will give you the same principle of notification and observers.

You will need a viewModel conforms to ObservableObject, then you will use @Published property wrapper, lets us easily construct types that emit signals whenever some of their properties were changed.

ViewModel.swift

```
enum ViewState {
  case loading
  case loaded
  case showCoachMark
  case hideCoachMark
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var state: ViewState = .loading
    ..... 
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import Combine
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

      private let viewModel = ViewModel()
      private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
      
      override func viewDidLoad(){
         cancellable = viewModel.$state.sink { value in
             // call tableview.isScrollEnabled = true/false
             // Please push this back to the main thread if the state has
             // been fetched via a request call 
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is simple trick that can answer your question:

```
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var tableView: UITableView? // declare a weak reference to your tableView that contains this cell
    
    func disableScroll() {
        tableView?.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
    
    func enableScroll() {
        tableView?.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell: YourTableViewCell = ...
    cell.tableView = tableView // assign this tableView to weak ref of tableView in YourTableViewCell
}
```

More isolation and loose-coupling:

```
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var onScrollEnabledChange: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    
    func disableScroll() {
        onScrollEnabledChange?(false)
    }
    
    func enableScroll() {
        onScrollEnabledChange?(true)
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell: YourTableViewCell = ...
    
    cell.onScrollEnabledChange = { isEnabled in
        // update above tableView's isScrollEnabled
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = isEnabled
    }
}
```

For a real solution:

In your BookViewModel.swift

```
import Foundation
import Combine

struct BookItemModel {
    let name: String
    var isDisplayingMark: Bool = true
}

enum DataLoadingState: Int {
    case new, loading, finish
}

struct BookViewModelInput {
    let loadData = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}

struct BookViewModelOutput {
    let dataLoadingState = PassthroughSubject<DataLoadingState,Never>()
}

protocol IBookViewModel {
    var input: BookViewModelInput { get }
    var output: BookViewModelOutput { get }
    func binding()
    
    func clickCoachMark(index: Int)
    func getItemCount() -> Int
    func getItemAt(index: Int) -> BookItemModel
}

class BookViewModel: IBookViewModel {

    private let _input = BookViewModelInput()
    var input: BookViewModelInput { return self._input }
    private let _output = BookViewModelOutput()
    var output: BookViewModelOutput { return self._output }
    
    private var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private lazy var defaultQueue: DispatchQueue = {
        let id = UUID().uuidString
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "BookViewModel.\(id)", attributes: .concurrent)
        return queue
    }()
    
    private var _books: [BookItemModel] = []
    
    // MARK: - Function implementation
    func binding() {
        self._input.loadData
            .receive(on: self.defaultQueue)
            .sink {[unowned self] in
                // this is event triggered from UI
                // your screen own this BookViewModel, same life-cycle, so you can refer to self with unowned
                
                // call your async data fetching
                self.fetchData()
            }.store(in: &self.cancellable)
    }
    
    func clickCoachMark(index: Int) {
        self._books[index].isDisplayingMark = false
        self._output.dataLoadingState.send(.finish) // trigger reloadData() again
    }
    
    // MARK: - Output handling
    func getItemCount() -> Int {
        return self._books.count
    }
    
    func getItemAt(index: Int) -> BookItemModel {
        return self._books[index]
    }
    
    // MARK: - Input handling
    private func fetchData() {
        self._output.dataLoadingState.send(.loading)
        
        // trigger block after 1 sec from now
        self.defaultQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) { [weak self] in
            
            // Update data first
            self?._books = Array(1...5).map({ BookItemModel(name: "\($0)") })
            // then trigger new state
            self?._output.dataLoadingState.send(.finish)
        }
    }
}
```

In your BookViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Combine

// I mostly name it as ABCScreen: UIViewController
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    private var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var viewModel: IBookViewModel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.setupListView()
        
        // you can make a base class that trigger binding() on initialization then make BookViewModel become its subclass
        self.viewModel.binding()
        self.binding()
        
        self.viewModel.input.loadData.send() // Void data type here, you can pass nothing as argument.
    }
    
    private func setupListView() {
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BookItemTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BookItemTableCell")
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    // here we are binding for output
    private func binding() {
        
        self.viewModel.output.dataLoadingState
            .sink {[weak self] newState in
                guard let _self = self else { return } // unwrapping optional self
                
                // alway use weak self to refer to self in block that is triggered from viewModel
                // because it can be async execution, different life-cycle with self (your screen)
                
                // Perform some big data updating here
                
                // This block is triggered from viewModel's defaultQueue
                // it is not mainQueue to update UI
                // Then switch to main queue to update UI,
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    _self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true // reset on each reloadData()
                    _self.tableView.reloadData() // refresh to update UI by new data

                    switch newState {
                    case .finish: _self.[hideLoadingIndicator]
                    case .loading: _self.[showLoadingIndicator]
                    case .new: break // do nothing, new is just initial-value
                    }
                }
            }.store(in: &self.cancellable)
    }
}

extension YourViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.viewModel.getItemCount()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookItemTableCell", for: indexPath) as! BookItemTableCell
        let item = self.viewModel.getItemAt(index: indexPath.row)
        
        cell.setupUI(with: item)
        cell.onClickCoachMark = { [unowned self] in
            self.viewModel.clickCoachMark(index: indexPath.row)
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let item = self.viewModel.getItemAt(index: indexPath.row)
        // if there is atleast one book need to show coachMark -> disable scrolling
        if item.isDisplayingMark {
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }
    
}

extension YourViewController {
    
    // You will init YourViewController like below:
    // let screen = YourViewController.build()
    // navigationController.push(screen)
    static func build() -> YourViewController {
        let view = YourViewController()
        view.viewModel = BookViewModel() // inject by setter
        return view
    }
}
```

In your BookItemTableCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class BookItemTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var onClickCoachMark: (() -> Void)?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    // Button click handler
    func clickOnCoachMark() {
        self.hideCoachMark()
        self.onClickCoachMark?()
    }
    
    func setupUI(with item: BookItemModel) {
        if item.isDisplayingMark {
            self.showCoachMark()
        } else {
            self.hideCoachMark()
        }
    }
    
    private func hideCoachMark() {}
    private func showCoachMark() {}
}
```

Comment: Interesting..I'll mark as accepted after trying it. 

Comment: You don’t want to let a cell to know anything about the tableview. In order to follow the clean architecture concept. The cell Just needs to take care of its own work, and follow single responsibility.

Comment: @TranTo TableView or TableViewCell is still UI and placed in PRESENTATION layer.
This doesn't violate the Clean Arch rule. Currently, It is pointing to UITableView (a universal class), not a specific one. The isolation and tight coupling are still applied.
Clean Code is way much different from Clean Arch.

THEJAS: For more Isolation, we can use the callback (closure). Let me update this for you.

Comment: What is the difference between clean code and clean arch? IMO they’re overlapping in iOS development context. They’re not way much different, keen to hear what you say bout this

Comment: @TranTo You need to research more about Clean Code and Clean Architecture. 
ContainerView and SubView are is in the same layer or same place/area. There is no Architecture here.

Clean code is how you write it for "that is easy to understand and easy to change".
If you put the UITableView here it is way much easier to understand but it is TIGHT-COUPLING.
Clean architecture is how you organize it. Writing is just a small step in organizing.

You can write a shitty code in Clean Arch too. 
And you can write a clean code in Bad Structure also.

Comment: The problem here is how can you use UITableViewCell correctly without UITableView? UITableViewCell needs to make sure that it has a ref to UITableView to do something. 

You need to classify that Data logic and UI logic.

Comment: My point is still stand. Here is the article for you @Neklas. clevercoder.net/2018/09/08/clean-architecture-summary-review/… code is a subset of clean architecture. To have clean architecture, you will need to have clean code. So there is nothing wrong in my statement.

Comment: Here is my final comment to make it more clear. I said: "Clean Code is way much different from Clean Arch". It doesn't mean that they don't relate to each other. Clean bricklaying is not like a Clean house design. But Clean bricklaying is a part/step/phase of Clean house design. Applying rules to Real world issues that need to be flexible, careful not to spam it then call it "Clean...".

If you warn me about REAL Clean stuff, let me add more examples in my answer.